# Issue: “OSError: /usr/lib/libyara.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” while running cuckoo.py

Tags: ubuntu, yara

I have installed cuckoo and all the dependencies and have also created VM using virtual box.
I am getting an error `"OSError: /usr/lib/libyara.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"` whenever i try to run cuckoo.py using python

I have tried searching in all forums and also tested whether yara is installed properly. It seems to be working fine using terminal. Checked that libyara.so is present in /usr/local/lib and python or cuckoo is checking in /usr/lib/

Also tried updating local library using

`sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig`

I have installed yara using tar ball. Have also used --enable-cuckoo --enable-magic args too.

Where might have I gone wrong?

Configuration of my system: 
Ubuntu 16.04;
python 2.7;
yara 3.4.0

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue but mine was stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/lib/libyara.so`

Creating the *soft-link* to that Location solved the issue

```
*ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/lib/libyara.so /usr/lib/libyara.so*
```

Answer (score 5):

According to official documentation, It means that the loader is not finding the `libyara` library which is located in `/usr/local/lib`. In some Linux flavors the loader doesn’t look for libraries in this path by default, we must instruct him to do so by adding `/usr/local/lib` to the loader configuration file `/etc/ld.so.conf`:

```
sudo echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

your script is looking for the lib in /usr/lib/libyara.so  but you said the lib is in /usr/local/lib

i'd create as softlink to fix this.

ln -s /usr/local/lib/libyara.so /usr/lib/libyara.so

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had created soft link and tried. This time it is throwing error `"AttributeError: /usr/lib/libyara.so: undefined symbol: lookup_rule"`

Comment: I was also getting this error. Running `find / -name libyara.so` revealed two files: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyara.so` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/lib/libyara.so`. Creating a symlink to the first resulted in the error. Creating a symlink to the second resulted in no error.

Comment: makes sense. the first error it was looking for the library in the wrong place the second was a library mismatch which you solved by finding and creating the soft link to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

If soft link is not working

`cp /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/lib/libyara.so /usr/lib/`

Comment: Provide an answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this link to resolve

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29428/

```
apt list --installed |grep yara                                                                                                      

libyara4/kali-rolling,now 4.0.5-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-yara/kali-rolling,now 4.0.4-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]





apt remove python3-yara/kali-rolling  
apt remove libyara4/kali-rolling
```

This may be possibly caused due to multiple version of yara in system.

Yara started working well after this change.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual environment and install requirement.txt inside it, then complete the installation steps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Seems to be two different packages.

The one I was looking for was `yara-python` instead of only `yara`.

Fixed it with:

```bash
$ python3 -m pip uninstall yara
$ python3 -m pip install yara-python
```